# Remove custom Domain from App engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I want to remove the custom domain from one project and add it to another.
I removed the txt node from DNS provider(namecheap in my case).

Sorry if i sound like newbie in this but would really appreciate any help in this.

Answer (score 1):

I used the SDK to delete it and it worked

use the command

`gcloud app domain-mappings delete <your-domain-here>`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage custom domains at this link: https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/domains

Just click the rubbish bin on the right and that should remove it :)

Comment: I had already removed the mapping from custom domain, so later i same added custom in my another project but it is still pointing to my previous project A records :(

Comment: I there a way i can remove from add a domain list?

Comment: It takes a bit of time (~24 hours) for A records to update - perhaps that's the problem?

Comment: @kapoorji you can remove it thru [Google Webmaster Central Panel](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home)